# Why Android SQLiteDatabase use String array for arguments input?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

if you use SQLite in Android you must know this query method:

```
Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, ...)
```

The part made me curious about its design is: Android force us to pass query arguments as a String array (`String[] selectionArgs`). This could have some drawbacks:

- If you want to pass an Integer as argument, you must first convert it to String (`yourInt + ""`, or `String.valueOf(yourInt)`), this creates a lot of temporary String objects.
- If you only need to use 1 argument, then you must create an array with only 1 item.

It's much easier if the argument input is `Object... selectionArgs`, which you **can pass Integer value, or use single String without creating an array**.

I don't know why Android creators did this? May be because String is immutable, then protect you from SQL Injection?